# Navber doesn't update contents on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a dynamic language switcher using Javascript. Its functionality works fine on desktop browsers. On mobile devices, however, the contents of the navbar doesn't update. Everything else does update though.

Is there a function that allows me to refresh/recreate the navbar with the new contents?

index.html

```
      <nav class="nav-menu">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="drop-down"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="portfolio/gallery.html" id="galleryNavID">Gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="portfolio/presentations.html" id="presentationsNavID">Presentations</a></li>
              <li><a href="portfolio/papers.html" id="papersNavID">Papers</a></li>
              <li><a href="portfolio/articles.html" id="articlesNavID">Articles</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#faq">Links</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact" id="contactNavID">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="drop-down" id="langNavID">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="images/uk.png" width="30" height="20"></img>
            </a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" onclick="toGerman();return false;"><img src="images/germany.png" width="30" height="20"></img></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
```

lang.js

```
function toGerman()
{
  document.getElementById('galleryNavID').innerHTML = "Gallerie";
  document.getElementById('presentationsNavID').innerHTML = "Vorträge";
  document.getElementById('papersNavID').innerHTML = "Papiere";
  document.getElementById('articlesNavID').innerHTML = "Artiklen";
  document.getElementById('contactNavID').innerHTML = "Kontakt";
  document.getElementById('langNavID').innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="toEnglish();return false;"><img src="images/germany.png" width="30" height="20"></img></a><ul><li><a href="#" onclick="toEnglish();return false;"><img src="images/uk.png" width="30" height="20"></img></a></li></ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing wrong but it works fine for me on mobile.
I replaced the images with text and included the "toEnglish" function.

How are you testing on mobile?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
      function toGerman() {
        document.getElementById("galleryNavID").innerHTML = "Gallerie";
        document.getElementById("presentationsNavID").innerHTML = "Vorträge";
        document.getElementById("papersNavID").innerHTML = "Papiere";
        document.getElementById("articlesNavID").innerHTML = "Artikel";
        document.getElementById("contactNavID").innerHTML = "Kontakt";
        document.getElementById("langNavID").innerHTML = `
          <a href="#">German</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" onclick="toEnglish()">UK</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        `;
      }

      function toEnglish() {
        document.getElementById("galleryNavID").innerHTML = "Gallery";
        document.getElementById("presentationsNavID").innerHTML =
          "Presentations";
        document.getElementById("papersNavID").innerHTML = "Papers";
        document.getElementById("articlesNavID").innerHTML = "Articles";
        document.getElementById("contactNavID").innerHTML = "Contact";
        document.getElementById("langNavID").innerHTML = `
          <a href="#"> UK </a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" onclick="toGerman();">German</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        `;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="nav-menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="drop-down">
          <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="portfolio/gallery.html" id="galleryNavID">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="portfolio/presentations.html" id="presentationsNavID"
                >Presentations</a
              >
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="portfolio/papers.html" id="papersNavID">Papers</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="portfolio/articles.html" id="articlesNavID">Articles</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#faq">Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" id="contactNavID">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="drop-down" id="langNavID">
          <a href="#"> UK </a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" onclick="toGerman();">German</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was running the website through localhost on my Mac using both my iPhone and chrome developer console's mobile functionality, I have the toEnglish() function as well, I just forgot to include it.

Comment: I made things more reusable and now it uses just one function "toLanguage".
I tried it on my Android phone by using the "live server" extension in vscode.
You can use your local network IP and type it into your phone's browser and use the port (default: 5500) from the extension to access your page.
-> 192.168.X.X:5500

v2: [https://jsbin.com/biliwowifu/edit?html,js,output](https://jsbin.com/biliwowifu/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I tried your method. I recorded my screen to show you that nothing happens. Same as with my method. Link is here: https://streamable.com/t1hk29

Answer (score 0):

How about this, would that work for you?

```js
function toGerman()
{
  document.getElementById('galleryNavID').innerHTML = "Gallerie";
  document.getElementById('presentationsNavID').innerHTML = "Vorträge";
  document.getElementById('papersNavID').innerHTML = "Papiere";
  document.getElementById('articlesNavID').innerHTML = "Artiklen";
  document.getElementById('contactNavID').innerHTML = "Kontakt";
}

function toEnglish()
{
  document.getElementById('galleryNavID').innerHTML = "Gallery";
  document.getElementById('presentationsNavID').innerHTML = "Presentations";
  document.getElementById('papersNavID').innerHTML = "Papers";
  document.getElementById('articlesNavID').innerHTML = "Articles";
  document.getElementById('contactNavID').innerHTML = "Contact";
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration:none!important;
  color:black!important;
  
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration:underline!important;
}
```

```html
      <nav class="nav-menu">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="drop-down"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="portfolio/gallery.html" id="galleryNavID">Gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="portfolio/presentations.html" id="presentationsNavID">Presentations</a></li>
              <li><a href="portfolio/papers.html" id="papersNavID">Papers</a></li>
              <li><a href="portfolio/articles.html" id="articlesNavID">Articles</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#faq">Links</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact" id="contactNavID">Contact</a></li>
          <li>Choose language</li>
            <ul>
              <li class="drop-down" id="langNavID">
            <a href="#" onclick="toEnglish();return false;">
              English (UK)
            </a></li>
              <li><a href="#" onclick="toGerman();return false;">German</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Works fine on my Samsung and my iPhone 8.

Comment: Well, it works for me, for Supportic and I just tested it in Dev Tools and it also works when emulating iOS phones. I suggest clearing your cache and/or testing on other devices than your current iPhone. Maybe also test in Chrome for iPhone, not Safari, etc. try to make it work, as this code works 100% on mobiles I can guarantee that.

Comment: Also, I think you should try it on a live server, not on a localhost setup or other things like that.